# How to change system fields in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, administration

I have to insert 1000 record into the Account object. My concern is if I insert a record the Created Date is set to today's date automatically. Is it possible to set the Created Date or Last Modified Date fields manually?

Answer (score 5):

You can contact Salesforce.com support and have them grant the ability to edit certain system fields (such as `CreatedDate` or `CreatedById`). In my experience they prefer to only allow this for a short period of time, such as the duration of a data migration run. More information on system fields is available [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/system_fields.htm).